# INSERT IGNORE still inserting even with warning

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert, insert-update

I have this Mysql Query:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table1 (device_id, august) VALUES ((SELECT id from table2 where hostname='hostname'), 1)ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE august = august + 1;
```

For some hostnames the result from `(SELECT id from table2 where hostname='hostname')` is NULL and in that case I don't want anything inserted in the table and that's why I set the `device_id` column **as primary key**.

If I use `IGNORE` a warning is raised but the value `august` still gets incremented for a column with device_id = 0 (default value for that column) and I don't want that.

If I remove `IGNORE` an error is raised and nothing inserted. The problem is that I don't want to generate errors (and I don't want to use a try/catch).

Is there a way in MySQL so I can do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think having both IGNORE and ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE in the same query doesn't quite make sense.

I think this is what you want:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (device_id, august) (
    SELECT id, 1 from table2 where hostname='hostname'
) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE august = august + 1;
```